# Check if file exists with different extension?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am starting out in photoshop with a `.tif` file. I run a script which adds some layers etc and then i save the file as a `.psd` in a new folder.

The problem i am having is checking to see if a `.psd` file already exists with the same name. My goal is to simply close down the `.tif` file without saving if a `.psd` with the same name appears in the folder.

Here is my save code:

```
//Save document
var savePath = Folder(doc.path.parent) + "/new_folder/";
saveFile = new File(savePath);
saveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions;
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
if ( WHAT SHOULD I BE ASKING HERE? ) {
    doc.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
} else {
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);    
}
```

I'm stuck with what add to the `if` function? I've tried `.exists` but it's not working because the current file is still in `.tif` mode and hasn't saved to `.psd` yet. So it just keeps on saving and overwriting the previous saved `.psd`

Any help would be most welcome. :)

EDIT:

Thought i had it working with this but still no luck:

```
//Strip .tif and add .psd to file name
var docName = doc.name;
PSDName = docName.substr(0,docName.length-3);    
PSDName = PSDName + "psd";  


//Save document
var savePath = Folder(doc.path.parent) + "/new_folder/";
saveFile = new File(savePath);
saveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions;
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
var savedFile = savePath + "/" + PSDName
if (! savedFile.exists ) {
    doc.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
} else {
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

}
```

the `if` statement is returning false every time and the doc is not saving. If i take away the `!` it saves every time.

Comment: your making a `new file` with a folder, where is the file name?

Comment: i can get the name of the file using `doc.name` ( i've stored `app.activeDocuments` to the variable `doc`) The `Folder` is just my save path for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new variable with the filename that you want to test - i.e. the name of the `.PSD` file and use that. For example, strip off the `TIF` and replace it with `PSD` then use `.exists`.

```
var ImageName = activeDocument.name;
PSDName = ImageName.substr(0,ImageName.length-3);    // Strip "TIF" from end
PSDName = PSDName + "psd";                           // Add on "PSD" instead
```

If you need to debug your script, you can do something like this:

```
// Change Debug=1 for extra debugging messages, Debug=0 for no messages
var Debug=1;
...
if(Debug)alert(PSDName);
...
if(Debug)alert("File exists");
```

Comment: Thankyou. I have it working now.My condition statement is: `if (! saveFile + PSDName.exists )`

Comment: Excellent! I love it when a plan comes together. For your future reference, this is my Photoshop scripting "bible"... http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_javascript_ref.pdf

Comment: Many thanks for the reference. very handy :) Unfortunately i thought i had it working but i can't find anything in the ref to help me out. Depending on if i have the `!` in the `if` statement, it either saves every time or not at all. I've put the code in the edit above. I am sure i'm not linking to the file properly but i've tried every combination possible inside the `if` statement and nothing is working.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer to see how to debug. Try doing an `alert()` with the name of the file you are testing to see if it is being formed correctly. Also try testing a simple, hard-coded filename like `~/Desktop/fred` then create the file in the Finder and run your Photoshop script and then delete the file and try again to see if your script is detecting it properly. Then progress to the full, intended filename after that works.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate all the help! I've managed to solve the problem. I had to directly append the `.exists` to the `File()` function. So, my `if` statement now look like this: `if (! File(savedFile).exists )` I made new variable for `savedFile` which pointed to the correct path and filename. Thanks again! :)